# Eclipse snippet grouping

Tags: eclipse, dreamweaver, grouping, code-snippets

I'm in a process of transitioning from Dreamweaver to Eclipse when it comes to PHP Development and I have to admit that Eclipse offers brilliant features as far as class browsing and syntax completion is concerned. 
  I'm using code snippets as a mechanism that really speeds up a process of developing an app.  I was playing around with snippets in Eclipse and they look very similar, with the only difference that I can't find a way of **grouping the snippets**. Ie. in Dreamweaver I had code snippets that were referring to our DB class (for connecting, fetching fields etc.), for session handling etc. In Eclipse, however, I can create snippets but they are just in one big list. Is there any way of grouping them or using any 3rd party tool (commercial?) for this that you could recommend?

Thanks, 
Paul

Comment: BTW, to give you a hint of what I would like to achieve, here's a link for how it looks in DW: http://i47.tinypic.com/mt2m94.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Just use the built-in Snippets tool from Eclipse

- Window > Show View > Other
- .....Type "Snippets" or Select General/Snippets
- Right-Mouse Click inside Area Click "Customize..."
- Then the following menu pops up.[image: Eclipse Snippets View]

Create a new "Category"

The categories cannot be nested, though. There is only one single level.